# Walking recognition

Tags: classification, matlab, pattern-recognition, feature-engineering, multi-class

I have walking samples from 20 different people. My aim is to detect which walking samples are from which person. I'm trying to achieve this by extracting "walking cycles" from each person's dataset and train a classifier with these "walking cycles". I extracted all cycles: found every walking cycle in the dataset and stored them independently into different rows of a matrix. Columns define time index and row defines amplitudes of walking cycles. How should I train a classifier with these extracted walking cycles? I am thinking of using time indexes as features but average walking cycle is about 20 time indices and I have around 100 complete walking cycle from each person(will be divided into training and test sets). I don't know the rules about curse of dimensionality and never experienced before so I have no idea if this design will work or not. I would be pleased to hear your suggestions about what I should do with these extracted "walking cycles".

I am sorry this is a copy-paste question from stackoverflow(deleted that post) because they told me this place is the right place to ask this question.

Here is an example walking sample. As you can see there is a periodic walking pattern and I extracted each of these periods and stored them in a matrix thinking to compare them with the incoming test dataset.

[image: matlab waveform]

And here is another subject's walking cycle samples.

[image]

Beware that I took a screenshot of a smooth part of cycles and even intrasubject variances can be quite high. These subjects didn't walk in their regular walking fashion for sure! Anyways, a paper suggested to average all cycles to create a template and compare it with test set's average, but I think creating an average template may hinder the performance(it might be negligible, but anyways I want to try it this way.)

Comment: you should link to some example images so people can look at the data

Comment: You should not post the same question to two different stackexchange sites (i.e. avoid cross-posting -- see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). What you should have done is flagged your other question and asked to have it moved here.

Comment: is it a problem to delete my other question and post the same here instead of moving it?

Comment: sorry could you link multiple subjects so one can identify differences

Comment: Done :) @seanv507